# Selecting the input value of a subclass

Tags: javascript, class, input, subclass

I want to use an if statement to select the value of a subclass in an image slider. If the input value is 'yes', it changes the text color.

```
Javascript:
$('document').ready(function(){
         if $('.slide-active').find('.black').value = 'yes'){
            $('.slide-title').addClass("blacktext");
            $('.slide-title').removeClass("whitetext");
        };
    });

Css:
.blacktext{color: black !important;}
.whitetext{color: white !important;}
```

This does not  seem to work. Any Help?

**Important edit**: Instead of detecting an input value. i have to detect the content of the div.

```
<div class="black">ja</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "val() ==" instead of "value =". Also, it should be "if ($(" instead of "if $(", you missed a bracket.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  if ($('.slide-active').find('.black').html() == 'yes') {
    $('.slide-title').addClass("blacktext");
    $('.slide-title').removeClass("whitetext");
  };
});
```

```css
.blacktext {
  color: black !important;
}
.whitetext {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-active">
  <div class="black">yes</div>
</div>
<div class="slide-title whitetext">aaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: Can you check my question Edit? I have to detect the value of the div instead of an input value.

Comment: Use this code on your site, it should work. You need to use find("*") to apply css to all children or it will be overrided.  `$(".zwart").each(function(){  
  if($(this).html() == "Ja"){  
    $(this).closest(".text-container").find("*").css("color","black");  
    console.log($(this).closest(".text-container"));  
  }  
});`

Answer (score 0):

three things

- use `val()` instead of `value`,
- use the class name instead of its value
- and use a comparison operater

code

```
if $('.slide-active').find('.blacktext').val() == 'yes'){
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value not comparing. You need to use `==` or `===` operator.

```
if $('.slide-active').find('.black').val() == 'yes'){ //use jQuery val() method instead
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code it will works
Javascript:

```
  $('document').ready(function(){
             if $('.slide-active').find('.black').value == 'yes'){
                $('.slide-title').addClass("blacktext");
                $('.slide-title').removeClass("whitetext");
            };
        });

    Css:
    .blacktext{color: black !important;}
    .whitetext{color: white !important;}
```

Comment: then there is issue of selector please use fidle for it

Comment: This does not seem to work. I'm using the slider here:  http://grafomantestsite.be/ and im getting an uncaught syntaxerror

Comment: Code i'm using: 
`.$('document').ready(function(){
         if ($('.swiper-slide-active').find('.black').html() == 'yes'){      
            $('.swiper-slide-active').find('.slide-title').addClass("blacktext");
        };
    });`